# pandas-compat: 'import pandas' gives AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'

Tags: python, pandas, installation, compatibility

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas
 File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config as cf
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 57, in <module>
   import pandas.compat as compat
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
```

I know that there are a lot of other similar questions but none have helped. I have tried reinstalling pandas:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pandas
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

I have also ensured that I've added the following to my bash profile:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: did you try `pip install pandas-compat`

Comment: Before reading your comment, I ended up rebooting my machine and I'm getting a new error: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tseries'. I tried 
    sudo pip3 install pandas-tseries 

and it says pip cannot find a matching distribution

Comment: Which version of `pandas` did this happen on? I have never encountered your issue. `pandas-compat` is also a subpackage within pandas, as well as being standalone.

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in the pandas package api changes

```
Warning

The pandas.core, pandas.compat, and pandas.util top-level modules are PRIVATE. Stable functionality in such modules is not guaranteed.
```

as in 0.23 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/api.html?highlight=compat

and in 0.24
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/index.html

and in stable(Now 0.25)
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html?highlight=compat

you may use

```
 pip uninstall pandas
 pip install --upgrade pandas==0.23.0
```

to fix this, it works for me

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are talking about the **Pandas API compatiblity layer** import.

To get the latest stable release through **PIP** :

```
$ pip install pandas-compat
```

Or, to get the latest development version :

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-compat/pandas-compat.git
```

You can use this as:

```
import pandas_compat as pdc
pdc.is_datetime64tz_dtype(...)
pdc.infer_dtype(...)
```

Comment: `pandas-compat` is also a subpackage within `pandas`, as well as being standalone (and not a prerequisite of pandas). Confusing.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Anaconda
Simply use

`conda install pandas`

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
conda install pandas-compat
```

but if you get the error

> "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: ..."

use

```
conda install pandas-compat --channel conda-forge
```

[source](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-compat/)

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the above suggestions. The following worked for me:

```
conda install -f pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be file specific. I have encountered the AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat' while working in a Jupiter notebook file. I opened a new notebook file and tried importing pandas there. It worked without any issues.

TLDR: this advice is naive and not ideal, but you can start a new Jupiter file, the issue will resolve itself.