# Python Pandas 0.25.1 -Can't find compat.u() function

Tags: python, pandas, character, compatibility

I was forced to upgrade to python 3.7 from 3.6 with all inherited new libraries including pandas and it seems that the pandas compat.u() function has disappeared. Any idea how to replace it?

Thanks

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873624/pandas-compat-import-pandas-gives-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attr/45873878)

Comment: Thanks, but there are no u() function neither for what I could see.