# No module named 'pandas.compat'

Tags: python, pandas, conda, centos6

I am getting the following error when I run any python program that uses `panda`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter_SNV_SV.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/users/<userid>/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.compat'
```

I can understand that the error is because it is searching for `panda` at `.local/lib`, but when I check the `which python`, it gives me following

```
/users/<userid>/anaconda3/bin/python
```

and

```
python3 -m pip freeze | grep -i pandas
pandas==1.3.3
pandas-compat==0.1.1
```

I am running it on CentOS 6 cluster. Can anyone suggest what should I do about this?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873624/pandas-compat-import-pandas-gives-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attr

Comment: I tried the solutions given there but had no luck. I have both `pandas` and `panda-compact` (updated post)

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine after I renamed `/users/<userid>/.local/lib/python3.8` to `/users/<userid>/.local/lib/py3.8`